# UITableView rows get unselectable

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have created a `UITAbleView` using xib file.

Here's the bug: when I push the detailed view and then send the app to background and then bring back up and go back to `tableView` then I can't select the first three rows.

It gets more interesting: when I select the 4th row and do the same thing (background and back) then that row becomes non responsive as well. Once I close the app and reopen, then all the rows are functionally again!!!

Any idea on what is causing this.

PS: made sure no other view is on top and blocking the `tableView`.

here's the code in `viewDidLoad`

```html
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame]; 
_tableView.delegate = self; _tableView.dataSource = self; 
UIView *clearView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 150)]; 
clearView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; _tableView.tableHeaderView = clearView; 
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ListCell"]; 
self.tableView.rowHeight = 150;
_tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone; _tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
[self.view addSubview:_tableView];
```

Comment: post some code. do you have anything on viewDidAppear, viewWillDisappear, ... ?

Comment: do you have anything in Application delegate method

Comment: Nothing in `AppDelegate`